# Path with boost lib

Tags: c++, boost

I have problem with boost library, when i try compilling simple program g++ show me "No such file or directory". I installed boost in /home/user/boost (there i have two folders "include" and  "lib"). I found bash script which no solved my problem :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/boost:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/boost/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your user-installed boost directory structure. If your include files are now in /home/user/boost/include/boost, then add a:

```
 g++ -I/home/user/boost/include/boost ...
```

to your compilation options. See **[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)**. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't help, this is only important for executing programs that look for shared libraries in the file system. It is like a "PATH" for dynamic link libraries. If you got your code compiled, then add the directory location of your boost libraries **in the link step** by:

```
 g++ -L/home/user/boost/lib
```

or whatever the location is.